What's wrong with this simple boolean expression in Ruby?
Here is my Ruby 3.2 code:
puts (1 and 0)
puts (1 and 0 and 1)

It prints 0 and then 1 (I'm expecting 0 in both cases). Can someone explain, why?

The numbers 1 and 0 aren't Boolean values in Ruby. They are both trueish in Ruby and, therefore, Ruby just returns the last value from each statement. When you use true and false instead, then both versions will return false. Btw. in Boolean expressions, using && instead of and would be more idiomatic.

First of all, and and or have very low precedence and are intended for control flow, e.g.
do_this or exit

(assuming do_this will return a truthy result upon success)
For boolean operations, you should use && and || instead.
Next, in Ruby there are two falsy values: false and nil. Every other value is considered truthy, including 0.
You might be looking for:
true && false
#=> false

true && false && true
#=> false

true && true && true
#=> true

If you are working with 1 and 0, bit operations might be useful: (see Integer#&)
1 & 0
#=> 0

1 & 0 & 1
#=> 0

1 & 1 & 1
#=> 1

